# Laravel - Join de 4 tablas con tabla pivot

Tags: laravel, join

**Buenas Tardes:**
Estoy desarrollando un sistema para un colegio.

Resulta que tengo 4 tablas: `users`, `levels`, `degrees`, `courses` y las tengo relacionadas de muchos a muchos en sus respectivas entidades. Para la relación uso una tabla Pivot en donde guardo los ids de cada tabla
Mi tabla Pivot -->> (table_course_degree_levels_users)

Necesito hacer Join entre ellas para mostrar en mi vista en la siguiente jerarquía:

`User -> Level -> Degree -> Course`

Comment: A tu pregunta le hacen falta muchos detalles para poderte ayudar, por favor lee [ask], edita y amplia por ejemplo colocando los modelos, si definiste las relaciones en ellos y ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: podrias agregar el como tienes relacionadas tus tablas (migrations) y los modelos donde haces las relacion (hasMany, belongTo, belongToMany, etcetera). Para ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por responder Edgar
mira asi tengo la migration de la tabla Pivot

```
Hola Edgar, mira así tengo la relacion de mi tabla pivot

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('course_degree_level_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            
            $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses');

            $table->integer('level_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('level_id')->references('id')->on('levels');

            $table->integer('degree_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('degree_id')->references('id')->on('degrees');

            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Mil disculpas soy nuevo en esta plataforma de hacer preguntas

1. Un usuario (que es un docente), puede tener muchos niveles, muchos grados y muchos cursos
2. un nivel (Por ejemplo Inicial Primaria o secundaria), puede tener muchos usuarios y, tambien muchos grados y muchos cursos
3. Un grado (puede ser 1ero, 2do, 3ero), puede tener muchos niveles, y pertenecer a muchos usuarios, y tener muchos cursos
4. y un curso, le pertenece a muchos grados, muchos niveles, y tambien a muchos usuarios

por tal, mis modelos los tengo asi

**Esto tengo en mi modelo Usuario**_

```
public function levels(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Level', 'course_degree_level_user');
    }

    
    public function degrees(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Degree', 'course_degree_level_user');
    }

    public function courses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course', 'course_degree_level_user');
    }
```

**Esto en mi modelo Levels (Niveles)**

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'course_degree_level_user');
    }

    
    public function degrees(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Degree', 'course_degree_level_user');
    }

    public function courses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course', 'course_degree_level_user');
    }
```

Esto tengo dentro de mi modelo Degree (Grados)

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'course_degree_level_user');
    }

    
    public function levels(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Level', 'course_degree_level_user');
    }

    public function courses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course', 'course_degree_level_user');
    }
```

**y esto en mi modelo Courses**

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'course_degree_level_user');
    }

    
    public function levels(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Level', 'course_degree_level_user');
    }

    public function degrees(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Degree', 'course_degree_level_user');
    }
```

ahora tengo una vista detalle del usuario, y quiero ver ahi
los niveles a los que enseña
de cada nivel a que grados eneseña
y en cada grado que cursos enseña

Gracias!! por sus respuestas

Comment: Esto debe ir como edición a la pregunta

Comment: Además más que las migraciones hacen falta los modelos

Comment: A tu pregunta le siguen haciendo falta detalles, por ejemplo un usuario tiene levels, degrees y courses?, posiblemente puedan estar existiendo N combinaciones por favor explica mejor tu escenario

Comment: Hola, respondí la spreguntaas sobre las relaciones y tambien expuse el codigo que tengo en los modelos